# Objective-C how to print out leading 0 for a float?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, format

How do you print out leading zeros for a float using the `NSString` type?

```
Input: 3.14
Desired output: 03.1

Using format @"%02.1f"
Output: 3.1
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want `@"04.1f"`. The 4 is the *total* width.

As you can see from the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265), the format strings conform to the [IEEE printf specification](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html).

The format string you've specified breaks down as follows:

> 0 -- Pad with zeros.
>   2 -- The entire resulting formatted value will have a minimum width of 2.
>   .1 -- Precision of 1 digit following the decimal point.

Comment: The _total width_ **includes** the decimal point, just saying

Answer (score 0):

For some reason you can't set the pre-decimal width on float numbers (maybe it's a bug you should report). This means you will have to split the number at the decimal format each the way you want and then merge them into one string (`@"%i.%i", preDec, postDec`).

Comment: It's not a bug. Whether it's what someone wants or not, it's how format strings are defined to work.

Comment: Still seems odd that it's not consistent between types. Perhaps a 'Feature Request' bug then...

Comment: It is consistent. For all types, the '2' he used specifies the minimum width of the resulting formatted value.

Comment: You CAN set it, just indirectly. For float it is the total width. Just adjust the total width such that the number of leading zeros is the required number.