# Obj-C Help on code to convert number (no known class method for selector)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4.5

Newbie on Obj-C here : )
I'm writing a code that converts numbers (mostly to control the zeros after the dot, 5.000 -> 5 or 5.00).
So, I got it to work but I really wanted to create a class to use it as I need.
Here is the working code:

MainViewController.h

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
[formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
NSString *convertedNumber = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:currentNumber]];
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",convertedNumber];
```

So, I just want to create a class that will do that for me and return the convertedNumber.
Here what I have done:

FormatNumber.h

```
@interface FormatNumber: NSNumber
{
    NSString *nf;
}

- (void) getNumber:(float)n1;
- (NSString *) retNumber;
@end
```

FormatNumber.m

```
@implementation FormatNumber;
-(void) getNumber:(float)n1

{

        NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
        [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
        nf = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat: n1]];

}

-(NSString *) retNumber; // As I cannot return something from void, I tried to do this way, don't know if it's the better
{
    return nf;
}
@end
```

MainViewController.h (trying to pass and get the value from the class)

```
currentNumber = currentNumber *10 + (float)[sender tag];
NSString *convertedNumber = 0;
FormatNumber *n1 = [[FormatNumber alloc] init];
[FormatNumber getNumber:currentNumber]; // No known class method for selector 'getNumber'
convertedNumber = [FormatNumber retNumber]; // No known class method for selector 'retNumber'
calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",convertedNumber];
```

Also, if there is a simple way to write this code I would appreciate some insights : )

Comment: The - prefix to a method makes it an instance method.  You want the + prefix

Comment: I don't know if this held but I remember reading something like you can put 540.f2f or something like that and the float will automatically have that many zeros afterwords. Some quick googling found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543896/objective-c-how-to-print-out-leading-0-for-a-float

Comment: How is that about the prefix? And I know I can use %.2f and so on, but I really wanted to understand and learn how to use classes (mainly how to pass and return values) and I'm thinking implementing the option to customize setMaximumFractionDigit, so the user will be able to choose the quantity of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using C-way, use %.2f(for 2 decimals) and/or %.4f(for four decimals) and %.0 for no decimal.

Here is a sample code for this.

```
float f=5.0000;
NSLog(@"res: %.2f", f); //5.00
NSLog(@"res: %.0f", f); //5
```

Comment: Thanks guys! I know I can use %.2f and so on, but I really wanted to understand and learn how to use classes (mainly how to pass and return values) and I'm thinking implementing the option to customize setMaximumFractionDigit, so the user will be able to choose the quantity of digits.