# Leading zeros for float in Swift

Tags: swift, floating-point

Here are some float value:

```
5.3
23.67
0.23
```

and I want them to be

```
05.30
23.67
00.23
```

Using `String(format: "%.2f", floatVar)` can make 2 digit following the decimal point but cannot add zero before it.

I've also tried `String(format: "%04.2f", floatVar)` as suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3543934/2603230) but it just display same as `%.2f`

Is there a clean way of doing this within the Swift standard libraries?

Comment: Try `"%*.2f"`. I remember this working in C.

Comment: @Arc676 it didn't return anything :(

Comment: `*` means that one more argument is used as the integer in place of `*`. It neither works better than `%5.2f` or worse, and it is sort of a useless suggestion without an explanation of what it does.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you want a quick and dirty solution:

```
String(format: "%05.2f", floatChar)
```

From [this documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/): `0` means pad it with leading zero. `5` is the minimum width, *including* the dot character.

---

The longer answer is that some locales use comma as the decimal separator. If you want to match the user's locale, use `NumberFormatter`:

```
let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.minimumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
formatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2

formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: floatChar))!
```

Comment: to clarify: 5 is the minimum width of the complete formatted String representing the original number, including the digits before the decimal separator, the decimal separator and the digits after the decimal separator. If floatValue is 3.14159265 and the String is created like this: String(format:"%06.2f", floatSample), then the resulting String is "003.14".

Answer (score 3):

Or I can try more powerful api of [NumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter)

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
// more settings
numberFormatter.minimumIntegerDigits = 2
```