# How to have 0 for unit digits in float value

Tags: ios, swift

How to have "0" for unit digits in float value  1.00 to 01.00

```
CGFloat totalAmount = 1.0

    "\(String(format: "%.2f",  amount?.totalAmount ?? 0.0))". -> 1.00 


Expecting result
00.50 
10000.55
1000.09
```

Comment: Unfortunately swift automatically converts 01 to 1 and 01.3 to 1.3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33447340/leading-zeros-for-float-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

To this specific scenario, as we are playing with CGFloat, i will opt for simpler String manipulation like below,

```
  var totalAmount: CGFloat? = 1.0
    var answer = String(format: "%.2f", totalAmount ?? 0.0)
    if totalAmount ?? 0 < 10{
        answer = "0" + answer
    }
    print(answer)
```